# Instructing MySQL to apply WHERE clause to rows returned by previous WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, where-clause

I have the following query:

```
  SELECT dt_stamp
    FROM claim_notes
   WHERE type_id             = 0
     AND dt_stamp           >= :dt_stamp
     AND DATE( dt_stamp )    = :date
     AND user_id             = :user_id
     AND note             LIKE :click_to_call
   ORDER BY dt_stamp
   LIMIT 1
```

The `claim_notes` table has about half a million rows, so this query runs very slowly since it has to search against the unindexed `note` column (which I can't do anything about).  I know that when the `type_id`, `dt_stamp`, and `user_id` conditions are applied, I'll be searching against about 60 rows instead of half a million.  But MySQL doesn't seem to apply these in order.  What I'd like to do is to see if there's a way to tell MySQL to only apply the `note LIKE :click_to_call` condition to the rows that meet the former conditions so that it's not searching all rows with this condition.

What I've come up with is this:

```
  SELECT dt_stamp
    FROM (
            SELECT *
              FROM claim_notes
             WHERE type_id           = 0
               AND dt_stamp         >= :dt_stamp
               AND DATE( dt_stamp )  = :date
               AND user_id           = :user_id
         )
     AND note LIKE :click_to_call
   ORDER BY dt_stamp
   LIMIT 1
```

This works and is extremely fast.  I'm just wondering if this is the right way to do this, or if there is a more official way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for the derived table solution as it is not performant. I'm surprised about the fact that having `=` and `>=` operators MySQL is going for the `LIKE` first.

Anyway, I'd say you could try adding some indexes on those fields and see what happens:

```
ALTER TABLE claim_notes ADD INDEX(type_id, user_id);
ALTER TABLE claim_notes ADD INDEX(dt_stamp);
```

The latter index won't actually improve the search on the indexes but rather the sorting of the results.

Of course, having an `EXPLAIN` of the query would help.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be necessary to do this.  The MySQL optimizer can handle it if you have multiple terms in your WHERE clause separated by `AND`.  Basically, it knows how to do "apply all the conditions you can using indexes, then apply unindexed expressions *only* to the remaining rows."

But choosing the right index is important.  A multi-column index is best for a series of `AND` terms than individual indexes.  MySQL can apply index intersection, but that's much less effective than finding the same rows with a single index.

A few logical rules apply to creating multi-column indexes:

- Conditions on unique columns are preferred over conditions on non-unique columns.
- Equality conditions (`=`) are preferred over ranges (`>=`, `IN`, `BETWEEN`, `!=`, etc.).
- After the first column in the index used for a range condition, subsequent columns won't use an index.
- Most of the time, searching the result of a function on a column (e.g. `DATE(dt_stamp)`) won't use an index.  It'd be better in that case to store a `DATE` data type and use `=` instead of `>=`.
- If the condition matches > 20% of the table, MySQL probably will decide to skip the index and do a table-scan anyway.

Here are some webinars by myself and my colleagues at Percona to help explain index design:

- [Tools and Techniques for Index Design](http://www.percona.com/webinars/tools-and-techniques-index-design)
- [MySQL Indexing: Best Practices](http://www.percona.com/webinars/2012-08-15-mysql-indexing-best-practices)
- [Advanced MySQL Query Tuning](http://www.percona.com/webinars/advanced-mysql-query-tuning)
- [Really Large Queries: Advanced Optimization Techniques](http://www.percona.com/webinars/really-large-queries-advanced-optimization-techniques)

You can get the slides for these webinars for free, and view the recording for free, but the recording requires registration.